# List installed application onto Windows clients via Microsoft SMS

Tags: windows, sms

I'm trying to understand how and if it is possible to list the installed applications of Windows clients via Microsoft SMS (System Management Server). What I can find it's only VB script snippet code to get the installed applications onto the client machine, but I don't know how SMS could aggregate these data.

Could anyone give me an indication or link?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  To get you started see [Creating Custom Reports By Using Configuration Manager 2007 SQL Views](http://blogs.technet.com/configurationmgr/archive/2008/10/30/creating-custom-reports-by-using-configuration-manager-2007-sql-views.aspx)

for the older version of SMS see

[Appendix E: SMS 2003 Custom Report Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc180025.aspx)

Comment: it is a lot of documentation to read...could you give me a link to an example? thanks a lot for your reply :-)